# SKU comparison for ADX VM

Tags: azure-data-explorer

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/manage-cluster-choose-sku) shows comparison among various VM SKUs available for ADX cluster. My question is about the following two SKUs:-

1. D14 v2  (Category: compute-optimized) , SSD:614 GB , Cores:16, RAM:112GB
2. DS14 v2 + 4 TB PS (Category: storage-optimized) , SSD:4TB , Cores:16 RAM:112GB

Purely looking at the numbers (SSD,RAM,Cores) it looks like #2 has everything #1 has but on top of that #2 also has 4TB of SSD -- whereas #1 has only 614GB of SSD. So based on that I will always choose #2 over #1. So what is the meaning of category here then? #1 falls in the category "compute-optimized" whereas #2 belongs to "storage-optimized". My question is that if a category is decided on the basis of configuration mentioned here then we should be able to call #2 as both storage as well as compute optimized because #2 has the same compute as #1 and then it has something extra over #1. Then why #2 is only listed as storage optimized. I am trying to understand if there an additional edge of using #1 over #2 for compute intensive jobs -- because if I just look at the numbers here I don't see any reason (apart from cost , which too is not much different though) why I shouldn't use #2 over #1. Probably #1 has something unique which is missing in #2 which is not specified in that [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/manage-cluster-choose-sku).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, it appears you're largely disregarding the consideration of cost - the following table (in the same doc you've linked-to) summarizes the main considerations for choosing a SKU - you can see one of them is `Cost per GB cache per core`.

Another example - let's assume you can reach the same total cache (SSD) size with either SKUs you mentioned - with one, your cluster will have X nodes, and with the other Y nodes. If Y > X, data in the other cluster will be distributed across more nodes, allowing more parallelism during [ingestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/capacitypolicy#ingestion-capacity) and queries. Of course, the cost for both options could be different.

Last - I would strongly recommend, given that cost isn't meaningless in your case, that you consult with the [cost estimator](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/AzureDataExplorerCostEstimator.html), and see how a different choice of SKU affects the total estimated cost of your cluster (given you know the volumes of data you're dealing with).

[image: pasted from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/manage-cluster-choose-sku]